# undefined method `open_and_process' for File:Class

Tags: ruby, undefined

Bellow is my file_open.rb

```
def File
   def self.open_and_process(*args)
    f = File.open(*args)
    yield f
    f.close
  end
end

File.open_and_process("testfile", "r") do |file|
  while line = file.gets
    puts line
  end
end
```

The error I always received is:
undefined method `open_and_process' for File:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: `def File` is not how you open the File class, it's `class File`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write `File's` class method, you could open your `File` class:

```
class File
  def self.open_and_process(*args)
    f = File.open(*args)
    yield f
    f.close
  end
end
```